# Configure 3 Mesos instance with 1 master using docker and docker-compose

Tags: docker, master-slave, mesos, docker-compose, marathon

By reading this article : [how-to-configure-a-production-ready-mesosphere-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-production-ready-mesosphere-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04), 
I wanted to start my own docker mesosphere using 3 server.

The setup is similar than the article, expect I use 4 dockerized server :

- Docker Zookeeper
- Docker Mesos Master
- Docker Mesos Slave
- Docker Marathon

I got really confused by the configuration files location, because they install the 4 components on the same machine.
Docker install use 4 different server, how do you apply the steps correctly using Docker.

I have

- Server 1 - prod02 - prod02.domain.com
- Server 2 - preprod02 - preprod02.domain.com
- Server 3 - prod01 - prod01.domain.com

Here is a the `docker-compose.yml` I started writting for running the **master mesosphere server 1**

```
zookeeper:
  build: zookeeper
  restart: always
  command: /usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground
  ports:
    - "2181:2181"
    - "2888:2888"
    - "3888:3888"
master:
  build: master
  restart: always
  environment:
    - MESOS_HOSTNAME=master.prod-02.example.com
    - MESOS_ZK=zk://prod-02.example.com:2181,prod-01.example.com:2181,preprod-02.example.com:2181/mesos
    - MESOS_QUORUM=1
    - MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos
    - MESOS_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/mesos
  volumes:
    - /srv/docker/mesos-master:/var/log/mesos
  ports:
    - "5050:5050"
slave:
  build: slave
  restart: always
  privileged: true
  environment:
    - MESOS_HOSTNAME=slave.prod-02.example.com
    - MESOS_MASTER=zk://prod-02.example.com:2181,prod-01.example.com:2181,preprod-02.example.com:2181/mesos
    - MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT=5mins #also in Dockerfile
    - MESOS_CONTAINERIZERS=docker,mesos
    - MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos
    - MESOS_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    - /sys:/sys:ro
    - /srv/docker/mesos-slave:/var/log/mesos
    - /srv/docker/mesos-data/docker.tar.gz:/etc/docker.tar.gz
  ports:
    - "5051:5051"
marathon:
  build: marathon
  restart: always
  environment:
    - MARATHON_HOSTNAME=marathon.prod-02.example.com
    - MARATHON_MASTER=zk://prod-02.example.com:2181,prod-01.example.com:2181,preprod-02.example.com:2181/mesos
    - MARATHON_ZK=zk://prod-02.example.com:2181,prod-01.example.com:2181,preprod-02.example.com:2181/marathon
  ports:
    - "8081:8080"
```

My project directory looks like this

- /prod-02

  - /marathon

    - Dockerfile
  - /master

    - Dockerfile
  - /slave

    - Dockerfile
  - /zookeeper

    - /assets
    - /conf

      - myid
      - zoo.cfg
  - docker-compose.yml

With this config, the master and slave serveur can't start , log is :

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F1016 12:12:49.976361     1 process.cpp:895] Failed to initialize: Failed to bind on XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5051: Cannot assign requested address: Cannot assign requested address [99]
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

I feel a bit lost due to lake of documentation, any help to configure is well appreciated

Comment: I've been working on a similar setup in https://github.com/dnephin/compose-swarm-sandbox/tree/with_mesos.  I have it working with just swarm, but it's not quite working with mesos yet.  What is the problem you're running into?  I think you might need to create images that run a script to do some of the configuration when it starts (by querying for the interface ip).

Comment: Ok the new configuration as totally changed so I have updated the fill with my 3 docker compose, the probleme is that the master election is done correctly but I can only see one slave at a time.

Comment: @dnephin, how to you get on each build the proper interface IP ? 
Using RUN docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' image_name_1 , it will add it to cache once, and will never refresh, if you have a good way to do so I am interested

Comment: I finally sort this out, what was missing was the external ip address MESOS_IP set for master and slave and also the net: host mode

Comment: @BigDong: If you figured it out you should make that an answer. You can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sort this out, what was missing was the external ip address MESOS_IP set for master and slave and also the net: host mode